# I'm trying to retrieve files from an ubuntu server using php 5.3.5 on a win7 machine

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to get all .log and .txt files from an Ubuntu server using php 5.3.5 (WAMP). This is my third day using php ... total beginner. I'm reading some doc, but trying to accomplish useful tasks along the way, as to reinforce my learning. Additionally, when I use the code below, the .txt and .log files are printed in the browser but there is no structure (hard to read). How can I print each path on a single line (not sure if it should be apart of the sub process like echo -e \n in the ssh2exec function or a line I should add to the php code? Any help is appreciated ... thanks!

```
 <?php
 if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
 if(!($ssh = ssh2_connect('10.5.32.12', 22))) {
     echo "fail: unable to establish connection\n"; 
 } else {

     if(!ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', '********')) {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate\n";
     } else {
         echo "Okay: Logged in  ... \n";  
         $stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'find / -name *.log -o -name *.txt');   
         stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
         $data = '';
         while($buffer = fread($stream, 4096)) {
             $data .= $buffer;
         }
         fclose($stream);
         echo $data; // user
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel instead of using `scp` or `rsync`?

Comment: @Dan Grossman - yeah I know, but it's an app that has many other features (all in one).

Comment: That app can `exec('scp ...');` ;)

Comment: `exec()` is NEVER a good idea when you can use built-in PHP functions like `ssh2_scp_recv()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shell, a new line is established by newline character (`"\n"`). In HTML, you'll need to either use CSS to make these newlines count:

```
echo '<div style="white-space: pre;">';
echo htmlspecialchars($data);
echo '</div>';
```

or insert `<br/>` elements:

```
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($data));
```

Here is a complete example, including download links and functionality:

```
<?php
if (! ($ssh = ssh2_connect('10.5.32.12', 22))) {
    throw new Exception('Connection failed');
}
if (!ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'root', '*******')) {
    throw new Exception('Authentication failed');
}
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
    $fn = $_GET['download'];
    if (! preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 .-_\\/]+(\\.txt|\\.log)$/', $fn)) {
        throw new Exception('access denied');
    }
    header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($ssh);
    $url = 'ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $fn;
    readfile($url);
    exit();
}

$stream = ssh2_exec($ssh, 'find / -name "*.log" -o -name "*.txt"');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$data = stream_get_contents($stream);
$files = explode("\n", $data);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($files as $f) {
    if ($f == '') continue;
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?download=' . urlencode($f);
    echo '<li><a href="' . htmlspecialchars($url) . '">';
    echo htmlspecialchars($f);
    echo '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I see ... any idea how I would get the files over to my local directory?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can make these paths href, so a user can click on one to open it?

Comment: @user706808 To download files, you should use the [SFTP subsystem](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp.php). You can write code like `$files = explode("\n", $data); foreach ($files as $f) {echo '<a href="/download.php?file=' . htmlspecialchars($f) . '">"' . htlmspecialchars($f) . '</a><br/>';` to generate links for all files, but you'll still have to implement download.php by connecting, and streaming the file from SFTP to the client. Have a look at the [`ssh2.sftp:`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ssh2.php) stream wrapper.

Comment: Can you give example with the ssh2_sftp and the code you wrote above? I see how I can get a particular file. But I'm trying to understand how to view all files as links. I don't have to download the files to my local machine, but I do need to perform a string search on them for which I can use grep with ssh2_exec. I need them to be links so If I want, I can open a particular file by clicking on it. Thanks!

Comment: @user706808 Added a detailed example.

Comment: Thanks! I have only 1 question ... can you tell me why when I do echo $ssh it shows ResourceId #2 and not the ip address?

Comment: @user706808 The precise string format of ssh handles is opaque, i.e. can change at any time. There is simply no reason why the string representation would include the IP address; since you can have multiple connections to the same IP, you'd have to include a numeric connection identifier anyway.